# 'Amc' Name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="second">
            @Html.RenderAction("Amc", "UserController")
  </div>
```

i am trying to add partial view in the index but it is not working. Besides it says  "**The name *Amc* Does not exist in current context"**

Comment: What is Amc? Are you trying to call a controller action??

Comment: Amc is the partial view that i have created through UserController

Comment: See my answer for more detail

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining that it does not exist in the current context because (from looking at the code above) it doesn't. It's not an object. If you want to render a partial you'll need to call the controller method that renders it.

For example:

```
@Html.RenderAction("Amc", "UserController") // If Amc is the controller method that renders the partial.
```

See [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/html-action-and-html-renderaction-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) for more information

Comment: yes , yes Amc is the controller method which is i am using as partial view. but still it is  not working. i had already visited https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/html-action-and-html-renderaction-in-Asp-Net-mvc/ this website. but i did not solve my problem

Comment: @KaranPophale From the snippet you have above, you dont have any quotation marks around `Amc`, so it will not work

Comment: sorry for that i did it now and the error occurred that "cannot imlicitly convert type 'void to 'object' "

Comment: @KaranPophale Could you show the code for the controller action. My guess is that you have a `void` controller action

Comment: ``` public ActionResult Amc()
        {
            return View();
        }```

Comment: @KaranPophale Shouldn't it be `return PartialView()` and personally, I like to put the name of the partialview in the `return PartialView("//view name")`

Comment: @KaranPophale No problem! Feel free to mark this as the correct answer for future viewers.